Query a SQLModel class with abstract definition
In this project, we have restricted imports between packages as follows:

We have a shared package.
We have a backend package.
Imports from the backend package to the shared package are not allowed, but imports from the shared package to the backend package are permitted. I cannot change this config.
Currently, some backend models, specifically SQLModel classes, need to be used in the shared package.

Here’s the solution I have implemented (paths are shortened):
in shared/models.py:
class SharedBaseSQLModel(SQLModel):
    # some shared fields like id
    # customized methods like save and read for shared package


class Job(SharedBaseSQLModel): # without table=True
     __abstract__ = True
     # some fileds like name, status

in backend/models.py:
from sqlmodel import SQLModel
from shared.models import Job as SharedJob


class BaseSQLModel(SQLModel):
   # customized methods like save and read for backend


class Job(BaseSQLModel, SharedJob, table=True): # here I use table=True
    # some extra methods

In shared I need to be able to do this query:
statement = select(Job).where(Job.name == 'foo').order_by(...).limit(...)
return session.exec(statement).all()

Error happens here: select(Job)

Current error: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got <class '..._shared.core.model.Job'>

Python 3.10.14

sqlalchemy-spanner==1.7.0

sqlmodel==0.0.18


As far as I understood, If I cannot use table=True, I cannot use select(MyModel).
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem? I'm also open to ideas for a better model design to handle situations like this.

So, I could find a working solution.
in shared/models.py:
class SharedBaseSQLModel(SQLModel):
    # some shared fields like id
    # customized methods like save and read for shared package


class Job(SharedBaseSQLModel, table=True): # with table=True <--
     __tablename__ = "job" # <--
     # some fileds like name, status

in backend/models.py:
from sqlmodel import SQLModel
from shared.models import Job as SharedJob


class BaseSQLModel(SQLModel):
   # customized methods like save and read for backend


class Job(BaseSQLModel, SharedJob, table=False): # with table=False <--
    # some extra methods
    __abstract__ = True # <--


But the main change was added here foo/bar/main.py:
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry

from shared.models import SharedBaseSQLModel

from backend.models import BaseSQLModel
from backend.core.models.job import Job # we use backend model here

combined_metadata = MetaData()

# pay attention to order first shared then backend
shared_metadata = SharedBaseSQLModel.metadata
backend_metadata = BaseSQLModel.metadata

for table in shared_metadata.tables.values():
    table.tometadata(combined_metadata)

for table in backend_metadata.tables.values():
    table.tometadata(combined_metadata)

mapper_registry = registry(metadata=combined_metadata)
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Job, Job.__table__) # this __table__ comes from shared!

combined_metadata.create_all(engine) # you need to import engine

In this way the CRUD operations are accessible from in shared and backend.
This definition should solve the sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError and sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got <class 'foo.bar.model.YourModel'
UPDATE:
There is another solution:
in shared/models.py:
class SharedBaseSQLModel(SQLModel):
    # some shared fields like id
    # customized methods like save and read for shared package


class BaseJob(SharedBaseSQLModel): # without table=True/False <--
     # some fileds like name, status

in backend/models.py:
from sqlmodel import SQLModel
from shared.models import import BaseJob


class BaseSQLModel(SQLModel):
   # customized methods like save and read for backend


class Job(BaseJob, BaseSQLModel, table=True): # with table=True <--
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True} # <-- 
    # when table=True everywhere that we need this model, 
    # we should add this line, apart from BaseJob
    # some extra methods


foo/bar/main.py
SharedBaseSQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

